# This page isn’t working on server side iis (.netcore 2.2)

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

I developed a web application which runs fine on local host but when i deploy it on server it give the error This page isn’t working error 500

Things i have done so far is updated asp.net core run time on server side

belowe is the code in programe file

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
```

below is the in my startup file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)


   {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        services.AddDbContext<RegConnString>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("contex1")));
        services.AddDbContext<SkillTestAppContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("context2")));
        services.AddSession();

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseSession();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

Below is the error i am getting when i deploy application on server

```
This page isn’t working 
somewebsite.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Comment: Did you install the (correct version of the) [runtime (including hosting bundle)](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) on the server?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg yes run time is already installed on the server

Comment: You're talking about a 500 error, then a 505, then a 500 again. I'm guessing that most likely it should be 500? Or is it actually a 505 error?

Comment: sorry typo. It is 500

Comment: Did you enable logging? In web.config set stdoutLogEnabled = true: `<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myapp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />`. This should help you to understand what the problem is.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg. Thank you for the hint. Actually my outputPath in angular.json was wrong.